# Laravel Equivalent of passing variables to functions in codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, variables, laravel-4, laravel-3

I am using `CodeIgniter` from 2 years and i am trying to move to `Laravel` and I saw many tutorials of how to use `Laravel` but i couldn't find any answers to how to pass variables to functions using the URL and without using routes like in `CodeIgniter` if i called this link
`site.com/users/edit/12`.

I would be calling the users controller , the edit function and passing a variable of value 12
how can i do the same in `Laravel` without using routes for every single function or using query strings which will make the `URL` ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.Hope that it will be helpful.......

route.php

```
Route::controller('users','UsersController');
```

UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extends BaseController
{       

    public function getEdit($value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

url

```
site.com/users/edit/12
```

output

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Laravel - 3](http://three.laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing) you may do it using something like this:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

But in later `versions` it's not available and you should explicitly declare the routes. Actually it's better to declare routes explicitly and this approach has many benefits too. This is a common problem that happens to developers who migrates from `CodeIgniter` but later they get motivated and if you use this you'll love this for sure.

You may read [this article](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil) by `Phil Sturgeon` who was the man behind the `CodeIgniter` framework, he discussed about it's down sides of this (automatic routing).

If you are using `Laravel - 4` then check the [Controllers Manual](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers), specially check out the `RESTful` and `Resourceful` controllers section, it may attract you but be familiar with explicit route declaration first.

Comment: The thing is i am trying to migrate a full e-commerce system that was originally built in codeigniter. if i remember correctly there was a controller with more than 200 functions it would be a tedious work to define a route for each one of them. there is no way to automate that without having to write a route for each function ?

Comment: There is no way in `L-4` but like i said; you may use `RESTful/Resourceful` controllers.